# Fill the div with different shapes without gaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, widget

[image: I draw example for easier understanding]
I'm trying to make a widget that would fill the div with smaller divs(which represent smaller content like images, text, links etc etc). The idea is that all the divs have in front decided sizes, for easier understanding i'll use simple units.
For example shapes from above image are:
A = 2x1
B = 1x2
C = 1x1
Widget-size = 2x10

Lets say i would like to feed in all kind of news, and all we know is:
- that we always get 10 news
- and the size of each news.
 My problem is that I would like to fill every possible gap if I have available shape. 
I tried simply floating elements left to fill in the widget, but that would leave me with gaps. So the question is how to approach this, so one would fill the widget with shapes of A, B, C without gaps.
**I'm aloud to use basic stuff like html/css/js/jquery, no plugins.**

Lets say we have example of news: A, C, B, A, C
[image: Achieved and desired example]

*I would only like to get direction, no need of full source code Ty*

Comment: Ty @Insane for editing (no repetition yet ) heh

Comment: It would be possible to do so with pure Css, anyway, what about looking to Bootstrap grid system ? I know you said "no plugins", but it's not it's framework ...

Comment: @Ganov13, would bootstrap help if i would feed in Different type of content? Example:
A/A/A/A/A/A/A/A/A/
A/B/C/C/A/B/C/C/
and so on, i don't know what the data base will select as top 10 news, all i'll get is 10 news with sizes.

Comment: i'll think so but Creative Enemy's answer would be better in your case.

Comment: Can the widget-size change? (from case to case)

Comment: There  is NO current CSS method that can determine the size of an element and fit it into a gap like that *automatically*...you need javascript. This is another masony.js question.

Comment: @IvanModric, widget size will be fixed as the width of the widest element, we will determinate specific sizes and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:
https://jsfiddle.net/uyz9fhcr/

I didn't do much testing and I assume there will be spaces (depending on the elements and number of columns).

The tile positions are processed one after another, each being placed in the **first** space big enough to contain it.

When changing stuff make sure to adjust the `width` and `height` of the `boxes` and `container`.